# Algorithm to find the closest 3 points that when triangulated cover another point

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Picture a canvas that has a bunch of points randomly dispersed around it. Now pick one of those points. How would you find the closest 3 points to it such that if you drew a triangle connecting those points it would cover the chosen point?

**Clarification:** By "closest", I mean minimum sum of distances to the point.

---

This is mostly out of curiosity. I thought it would be a good way to estimate the "value" of a point if it is unknown, but the surrounding points are known. With 3 surrounding points you could extrapolate the value. I haven't heard of a problem like this before, doesn't seem very trivial so I thought it might be a fun exercise, even if it's not the best way to estimate something.

Comment: How would you like to define "closest 3 points"?  Smallest average distance?  Smallest area triangle?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to minimize the triangle's surface? The product of the three distances?

Comment: I think you need to be more precise with your definition of "closest".  Triangle with minimum area?  Minimum sum of distances to the point?  Nearest point must be included in the triangle?

Comment: Clarified. Either would be fine I guess... but I don't want long/sliver triangles. I think minimum distance would be better at avoiding that.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem description is ambiguous. Which triangle are you after in this figure, the red one or the blue one?

[image: two triangles, neither of which is closer]

The blue triangle is closer based on lexicographic comparison of the distances of the points, while the red triangle is closer based on the sum of the distances of the points.

Edit: you clarified it to make it clear that you want the sum of distances to be minimized (the red triangle).

So, how about this sketch algorithm?

1. Assume that the chosen point is at the origin (makes description of algorithm easy).
2. Sort the points by distance from the origin: P(1) is closest, P(*n*) is farthest.
3. Start with *i* = 3, *s* = ∞.
4. For each triple of points P(*a*), P(*b*), P(*i*) with *a* < *b* < *i*, if the triangle contains the origin, let *s* = min(*s*, |P(*a*)| + |P(*b*)| + |P(*i*)|).
5. If *s* ≤ |P(1)| + |P(2)| + |P(*i*)|, stop.
6. If *i* = *n*, stop.
7. Otherwise, increment *i* and go back to step 4.

Obviously this is O(n³) in the worst case.

Here's a sketch of another algorithm. Consider all pairs of points (A, B). For a third point to make a triangle containing the origin, it must lie in the grey shaded region in this figure:

[image]

By representing the points in polar coordinates (*r*, θ) and sorting them according to θ, it is straightforward to examine all these points and pick the closest one to the origin.

This is also O(n³) in the worst case, but a sensible order of visiting pairs (A, B) should yield an early exit in many problem instances.

Comment: _Clarification: By "closest", I mean minimum sum of distances to the point._ See edit on Q.

Comment: BTW "triangle contains the origin" means "the sum of inter-points angles adds up Pi"

Answer (score 4):

1. Like @thejh suggests, sort your points by distance from the chosen point.
2. Starting with the first 3 points, look for a triangle covering the chosen point.
3. If no triangle is found, expand you range to include the next closest point, and try all combinations.
4. Once a triangle is found, you don't necessarily have the final answer.  However, you have now limited the final set of points to check.  The furthest possible point to check would be at a distance equal to the sum of the distances of the first triangle found.  Any further than this, and the sum of the distances is guaranteed to exceed the first triangle that was found.
5. Increase your range of points to include the last point whose distance <= the sum of the distances of the first triangle found.
6. Now check all combinations, and the answer is the triangle found from this set with the minimal sum of distances.

Comment: That sounds like it should work :) Sounds a bit like A* or something.

Answer (score 4):

Just a warning on the iterative method. You may find a triangle with 3 "near points" whose "length" is greater than another resulting by adding a more distant point to the set. Sorry, can't post this as a comment.

See Graph.
[image]

Red triangle has perimeter near 4 R while the black one has 3 Sqrt[3] -> 5.2 R

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why, after you've found one triangle, you need to keep searching until you can prove that the triangle you found is the minimum. See step 5 in my answer.

Comment: @Gareth Yep. Not all answers take care of that, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

second shot

**subsolution:** (analytic geometry basics, skip if you are familiar with this) finding point of the opposite half-plane

Example: Let's have two points: **A**=[a,b]=[2,3] and **B**=[c,d]=[4,1]. Find vector **u** = A-B = (2-4,3-1) = (-2,2). This vector is parallel to **AB** line, so is the vector (-1,1). The equation for this line is defined by vector **u** and point in **AB** (i.e. **A**):

```
X = 2 -1*t
Y = 3 +1*t
```

Where **t** is any real number. Get rid of **t**:

```
t = 2 - X
Y = 3 + t = 3 + (2 - X) = 5 - X
X + Y - 5 = 0
```

Any point that fits in this equation is in the line.

Now let's have another point to define the half-plane, i.e. **C**=[1,1], we get:

```
X + Y - 5 = 1 + 1 - 5 < 0
```

Any point with opposite non-equation sign is in another half-plane, which are these points:

```
X + Y - 5 > 0
```

**solution:** finding the minimum triangle that fits the point **S**

1. Find the closest point **P** as min(sqrt( (**Xp** - **Xs**)^2 + (**Yp** - **Ys**)^2 ))
2. Find perpendicular vector to **SP** as **u** = (-Yp+Ys,Xp-Xs)
3. Find two closest points **A**, **B** from the opposite half-plane to **sigma** = **pP** where **p** = **Su** (see subsolution), such as **A** is on the different site of line **q** = **SP** (see final part of the subsolution)
4. Now we have triangle **ABP** that covers **S**: calculate sum of distances |**SP**|+|**SA**|+|**SB**|
5. Find the second closest point to **S** and continue from 1. If the sum of distances is smaller than that in previous steps, remember it. Stop if **|SP|** is greater than the smallest sum of distances or no more points are available.

I hope this diagram makes it clear.
[image]

Comment: This seems to be O(n), should be fast enough with many points to calculate.

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear to me what kind of "sub-plane" you are defining in step 3. Do you mean "half-plane"? If so, which line bounds this half-plane? Your notation is also a bit strange: when you say "p = Su" what kind of vector multiplication do you mean here (dot or cross product?) or do you mean "p = S + u"? Maybe a diagram would make it clear.

Comment: @Gareth: indeed, sub-plane is half-plane (pardon my english). By p = Su I mean (line p is defined by point S and vector u). Diagram added, please correct if something is wrong or still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. It's clear now. But why do A and B have to be in opposite half-plane? Why couldn't one of them be in the half-plane sigma?

Comment: @Gareth: Good point. I presume, that the "opposite half-plane" condition does not "miss" some solution. In the diagram above, if the A point would be in sigma, we would not find the solution in step one, but later, when A or B would be the initial point. But I have no idea of proof / counterexample, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first shot:

1. split the space into quadrants
   with picked point at the [0,0]
   coords
2. find the closest point
   from each quadrant (so you have 4
   points)
3. any triangle from these
   points should be small enough (but not necesarilly the smallest)

Comment: true... first shot misses :-)

Answer (score -1):

Take the closest N=3 points. Check whether the triange fits. If not, increment N by one and try out all combinations. Do that until something fits or nothing does.

Comment: This will find a triangle such that the maximum point distance is minimized.  This may or may not be what @Mark means by "closest 3 points".  For example, if N=5, you may find a triangle using points 3, 4, and 5, and then stop.  But if you went further, you might find a triangle using points 1, 2, and 6.  If 1 and 2 are very close the the covered point, then this might be the desired answer.

Comment: Without actually having a counterexample, I suspect that will not guarantee to find the solution where the sum of distances is minimal.

Comment: But this is O(n^2) steps - and the problem "whether triangle fits" is not trivial, too.

Comment: Mmmm O(n^2) is when you have to check against the previous points, here you have to check against _combinations_ of previous points .. seems O(n^3)