# How do i find the smallest point P(x,y) containing triangle from a bunch of points?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, interpolation

This is something a human child can do, but I need a computer to do it :D

Guess you have a point P(x,y) and you have an array of points
`A = [P1, P2, P3, …]`

What i basically need to get is the 3 points that

- form a triangle that surrounds P
- form from those that surround P the smallest triangle possible

Well, of course I could just bruteforce it by calculating all possible triangles, barycentric interpolate if they're containing the point and compare the areas size of the resulting triangles, but this soon gets very time consuming.

I think this has been done before and is one of those ›if-you-know-the-name-of-the-algorythm-you-know-what-to-implement‹-problems.

I should add that if two triangles are reasonably close in size, than any of them would be a good solution, so in that case, the faster solution would be the better one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229454/algorithm-to-find-the-closest-3-points-that-when-triangulated-cover-another-poin

Comment: Is the triangle area a good quantity to determine the "smallest" triangle possible ? With this condition, a plane triangle with very long edges is a "better" triangle than an equilateral triangle. Area of the circumscribed triangle seems to be a better way to determine "small" triangle, and in this way, Delaunay's Triangulation is optimal.

Comment: @RaymoAisla: could you please explain? For me, the smallest triangle possible just is the triangle with the smallest size.

Comment: @rhavin `Smallest size` by area is doubtful criteria. Imagine that the smallest angle triangle is vry narrow and intersects all your point cloud - two close vertices at the most left side, and one vertex at the right side. Human child won't choose this triangle, but computer can.

Comment: If we consider in an orthonormal basis, the points A(0,0), B(0,1), C(1,0), D(10000,0) and E(5000,0.00001), the triangle ABC has an area of 0.5, and ADE of 0.05. However, the triangle ABC has for longest vertice sqrt(2), and ADE has 10000. ABC can fit in a small circle, ADE can't. So in most case, the triangle area is not a sufficient condition, because it doesn't take into account the shape.

Answer (score 2):

Build [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) for given set of points and find triangle containing the point.

Perhaps it will not the most optimal triangle, but algorithm is well-known and fast.